# Some Thoughts about Schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Closed Subschemes of an affine scheme are determined by ideals $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Consider the affine plane $\mathbb{A}^2=\text{Spec} k[x,y]$ then the ideal $(x,y)$ defines the origin as a closed point.

$\bf{Question\  1:}$ What subschemes are defined by $(x^2,y)$ and $(x,y^2)$ ?

Some thoughts: The subscheme  $(x^2,y)$ lies on the $x$-axis as $(y)\subseteq (x^2,y)$, thus in analogy with the idea that $(x^2)\subseteq k[x]$ defines an infinitesimal neighbourhood of the point $0$, we have that $(x^2,y)$ is the same infinitesimal neighbourhood of a point on a line but now embedded in the plane. Similarly, $(x,y^2)$ lies on the $y$ axis.

$\bf{Question\  2:}$ Gives a closed subscheme $\mathfrak{a}$ can one determine a reduced irreducible subscheme on which it lies ?

Some more thoughts, the subscheme $(x^2,xy,y^2)$ is the infinitesimal neighbourhood of the origin in the plane. But what about $(x^2,y^2)$ ? It does not seem to lie on some closed subscheme.

$\bf{Question\  3:}$ What geometric interpretation can we give to the closed subscheme defined by the ideal $(x^2,y^2)$ ?

Thanks in advance for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: I think Question 2 is not what you really want to ask: for example **all** your closed subschemes lie on $\mathbb A^2$, which is reduced and irreducible. And for general $X$,  the answer is  no for $\mathfrak a=(0)$ if $X$ is not itself reduced and irreducible...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg True, but I think I have more in mind a maximal prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \mathfrak{a}$. The spirit is more to understand what I see as the zoo of subschemes such that $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}=(x,y)$ by relating them to the (proper) closed subschemes on which they lie. For example $(x^2,y)$ does not lie on the $y$ axis as $(x)\not \subseteq (x^2,y)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\bullet$ Your remarks on Question 1 are quite correct.

$\bullet \bullet$As to Question 2:
 Neither the subscheme $V_1=V(x^2,y^2)\subset \mathbb A^2$ nor $V_2=V(x^2,xy,y^2)\subset \mathbb A^2$ can lie on a smooth curve $C$, whether that curve is embedded in $\mathbb A^2$ or not.
The reason is that the Zariski tangent space of the scheme $V_i$ (at its unique point!) is $2$- dimensional and thus is not a subspace of the $1$-dimensional Zariski tangent space of a smooth curve at any of its points $c\in C$.
However both of these schemes are subschemes of plenty of singular but reduced and integral curves: for example $V_1,V_2\subset V(y^2-x^3)\subset \mathbb A^2$.

$\bullet \bullet \bullet$ Question 3 has many answers.
The simplest might be that if you restrict some function $$F(X,Y)=a+bX+cY+dXY+eX^2+gY^2+\cdots\in \mathcal O( \mathbb A^2)=k[X,Y]$$ to $V_1$, you will obtain a function $$f(x,y)=a+bx+cy+dxy\in \mathcal O( V_1)=k[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^2)=k[x,y]$$ which remembers not only the value $F(0,0)=a$ of $F$  at the origin but also the derivative of $F$  in any direction: $$   \partial F_{(0,0)}(u,v)=bu+cv$$ Algebraic geometry is much closer to Advanced Calculus than is often realised!